# error mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, string given

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, string given

this is my  codes can anyone tell me what is wrong?

```
$result ="SELECT * FROM report" ;
if(mysqli_query($cons, $result)) {
echo("
<div class='sc'>
<table  id='to1' width='90%' border='0' cellspaceing='1' cellpadding='8' align='center'>
 <tr bgcolor='#9B7272'>
<td > ID </td>
<td > first_name </td>
<td > last_name </td>
<td > phone </td>
<td > address </td>
<td > email </td>
<td > birthdate </td>
<td > gender </td>
<td > city </td>
<td > dr_name </td>

</tr>

");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$ID         =$row['ID']; 
$first_name =$row['first_name'];
$last_name  =$row['last_name'];
$phone      =$row['phone'];
$address    =$row['address'];
$email      =$row['email'];
$birthdate  =$row['birthdate'];
$gender     =$row['gender'];
$city       =$row['city'];
$dr_name    =$row['dr_name'];

echo "  <tr bgcolor='#C7B8B8'>
```

Comment: You should pass the_result_ of `mysqli_query()` to `mysqli_fetch_array()`, not the query itself ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Problem**

You are missing how to pass the argument to [`mysqli_fetch_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php).

**Solution**

Therefore, this line:

```
if(mysqli_query($cons, $result)) {
```

should be

```
if($res = mysqli_query($cons, $result)) { // assign the return value of mysqli_query to $res
```

<sup>(FWIW, I'd go with `$res = mysqli_query($cons, $result);` then do `if($res) {`.)</sup>

And then do

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) // pass $res to mysqli_fetch_array instead of the query itself
```

**Why?**

You were giving to `mysqli_fetch_array()` - as an argument - the `string` that contains your query. That's not how it works. You should pass the return value of `mysqli_query()` instead. Therefore, you could also write: `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($cons, $result))) {}` (but it's not adviced, it is just to show you how it works).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment, you need to set a `$result` from your query and use that in your loop instead.

```
$qry ="SELECT * FROM report";
$result = mysqli_query($cons, $qry);
if ($result){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can write like this:-

```
$query = mysqli_query($cons,"SELECT * FROM items WHERE id = '$id'");
if (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0)
{
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
{
  $result=$row;
}
}
```